# Conditionally change values of a column with dplyr and the pipe function

Tags: r, pipe, dplyr, recode

I want to change specific values in a column to another value. I want to use the dplyr and the pipe function, and I don't want to create a vector and then replace those values. For example, in the iris dataset, in the Species column, I want to change the values that are equal to "setosa" to a new value called "new value". recode() does not work with data.frmaes.

```
library(tidyverse)
temp <- iris %>%
  recode(Species, "setosa" = "new value")
```

I only want to specify a change for one value, and keep the rest as is.

Using mutate() and replace() also doesn't work:

```
  mutate(Species = replace(Species, Species == "setosa", "new variable"))
```

I get this:

Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `Species`.
ℹ invalid factor level, NA generated
ℹ Input `Species` is `replace(Species, Species == "setosa", "new variable")`.
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = "new variable") :
invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. My question is not on how to change factor levels